# ruby File.expand_path strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

just encounter 2 problems regarding the File.expand_path api. would appreciate if anyone can help me on this :-)

Ruby: 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux] 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2

1.why Encoding.default_internal dose not affect encoding of File.expand_path?

```
2.1.5 :002 > Encoding.default_internal="utf-8"
 => "utf-8" 
2.1.5 :003 > File.expand_path("/").encoding
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

.

2.Why File.expand_path returns different encoding?

```
2.1.5 :007 > File.expand_path("/").encoding
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII> 
2.1.5 :008 > File.expand_path(".").encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `String#encoding` defaults to "US-ASCII".

My guess is that `String#encoding` inspects the string and detects if it contains any non-ascii characters, and in that case, returns "UTF-8".

The `/` path obviously doesn't contain any non-ascii characters, whereas your `.` path depends on your code's working directory, so if you have non-ascii characters somewhere in the path to your current working directory, then `String#encoding` will return "UTF-8".